# In what space does MoveIT plan paths?

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two questions about how does MoveIT plan paths:

1. If my target is defined in a task space, does MoveIT convert the target into c-space by solving IK and then plans in configuration space or does it look for a plan in task space and then converts trajectory into c-space?
2. If my target is defined as joint values does in convert it to corresponding task space pose using forward kinematics and looks for a path in a task space?

I am worried about it because if planning is always  performed in task space then collision detection requires to solve IK on each planning iteration which can work quite slow when IK is solved using Jacobian based solvers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295756/in-what-space-does-moveit-plan-paths?/) by [Long Smith](https://answers.ros.org/users/28619/long-smith/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2018-06-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

MoveIt and the planning library it uses, OMPL, are always planning in the C-space. The only IK that MoveIt has to do is to convert a Pose Goal into the robot configuration and then plans in the C-space using that configuration. If the robot is redundant, and multiple configurations can satisfy the given Pose Goal, then MoveIt samples several and plans to multiple goals.

---

Originally posted by [BryceWilley](https://answers.ros.org/users/33606/brycewilley/) with karma: 711 on 2018-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4